# how to call firebase cloud function within the same app in which it is created

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, gatsby

I created an gatsby website and also added firebase to the project by running `firebase init`.

I chose Cloud Functions and Firebase Hosting options for my website.

Now, I want to call the HTTP function created in the functions folder from the same website on button click.

May I do that?

Comment: @doug-stevenson Thanks for edit.

Comment: Don't know much about gatsby, but you can create an HTTP trigger cloud function and make an HTTP call to the function on button click. Is it not possible?

Comment: @AkshayJain  Yes, that is possible but I am just trying to do it by the mentioned way.

Comment: Almost certainly you can't call a function directly from the hosted site. Hosting and cloud functions are independent services and will be deployed separately. HTTP call would be the only way to call the cloud function or you will have to duplicate the code in hosting and cloud functions.

Answer (score 0):

By using **HTTPS Callable function**

Docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable